# Terraform regular expression to extract part of url

Tags: regex, terraform

I have a url like

```
postgres://some-url.com:23244/users-pool?sslmode=require
```

I basically need to match everything between `//` and `:` . So in this case I need `some-url.com`. I am trying this regular expression `/(?<=\/\/)(.*?)(?=\:)/gm`  and it works on online regex tools. Howeever when I try to do this on TF

```
regex("postgres://some-url.com:23244/users-pool?sslmode=require", "(?<=//)(.*?)(?=\:)")
```

I am getting

````
│
│   on <console-input> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│
│  Error: Invalid escape sequence
│
│   on <console-input> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ The symbol "/" is not a valid escape sequence selector.
╵

╷
│ Error: Invalid escape sequence
│
│   on <console-input> line 1:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ The symbol "/" is not a valid escape sequence selector.```


How can I do this on Terraform? Appreciate the help
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern should be **first**, not second:

```
regex("//(.*):", "postgres://some-url.com:23244/users-pool?sslmode=require")
```

Comment: aah! why dint I see that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If it should be between `//` and the first occurrence of `:` you can use a negated character class excluding matching the colon in between:

```
//([^:]*):
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/gpeooV/1).